# Problema con una consulta al hacer un WHERE con fechas

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un problema y es que en el momento que hago el where con la fecha no se porque, aunque exista en la base de datos algo con la misma fecha a la que la igualo no me saca nada por lo que siempre entra al if.

La fecha de la variable que utilizo para comparar la traigo por post desde un formulario con  un input type date.

```
$conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "basereserva");
$query="SELECT * from mesas where dia=".$fecha;
$resultado=mysqli_query($conexion, $query);

if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado)>0){
    print("Exite al menos un registro");

} else {
    print("No Existen registros");



    }
```

Comment: Intenta encerrar el valor en comillas asi: `$query="SELECT * from mesas where dia='".$fecha."'";`

Comment: sospecho que la fecha no esta llegando con el formato yyyy-MM-dd, si este es el caso, debes garantizar que la query la fecha tenga este formato.

Comment: ¿Cómo están las fechas almacenadas en la columna `dia` de la base de datos (pon un ejemplo)?  ¿Cómo es el valor de la variable `$fecha` (pon un ejemplo)?